# Wrap/Proxy Boilerplate from Methods

Tags: java, proxy

I'm not a Java specialist and wondering if I could wrap Methods that are only different in their middle to stop having boilerplatecode like this:

```
public boolean storeAnimals(Cage cage, Collection<Anmial> animals, IConfiguration configuration) {
    checkPrerequisite(cage);
    String cagePath = cage.getPath();
    AnimalStorage animalStore = AnimalStorage.openFile(cage, configuration);

    //***/
    do_sth_very_special
    //***/

    animalStore.closeFile();
    return true;
}

public Collection<Anmial> getRedAnimals(Cage cage, IConfiguration configuration) {
    checkPrerequisite(cage);
    String cagePath = cage.getPath();
    File animalStore = AnimalStorage.openFile(cage, configuration);

    //***/
    do_sth_very_special
    //***/

    animalStore.closeFile();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since java doesn't present a kind of closure, you could use an interface for it. In this case you could do something like:

```
public Collection<Anmial> commonMethod(Cage cage, IConfiguration configuration, Runnable runnable) {
    checkPrerequisite(cage);
    String cagePath = cage.getPath();
    File animalStore = AnimalStorage.openFile(cage, configuration);

    //***/
    runnable.run();
    //***/

    animalStore.closeFile();
    return result;
}
```

and you method would be something like:

```
public boolean storeAnimals(Cage cage, Collection<Anmial> animals, IConfiguration configuration) {
    commonMethod(cage, animals, configuration, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("something special");
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

of course the `Runnable` interface was taken just to exemplify the idea, you could implement an interface for your needs. If you need that the inner code accesses some variables defined outside you can pass it as parameters, and if the outside code needs to access some variables defined inside you could return them from the invocation.

You could define a generic interface like:

```
public interface Executable<ReturnType, ParameterType> {

    ReturnType execute(ParameterType parameter);

}
```

In case you need more parameters to execute the code, you could build a class containing all needed fields for the code execution. The same could be applied to the result.

This would be the idea to return a list of string:

```
new Executable<List<String>, Void>() {

    public List<String> execute(Void void) {
        // something special
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

[ParameterObject](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) could be used to solve the problem when you need to give more objects to the execution. Suppose you have one `Integer` and a `boolean` that needs to be given to the execution, this means you will have a class holding an `Integer` and a `boolean` like:

```
public class MyParameter {

    private boolean b;
    private Integer i;

    public MyParameter(Integer i, boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
        this.i = i;
    }

    // getters

}

new Executable<Void, MyParameter>() {

    public Void execute(MyParameter params) {
        // something special
        System.out.println(params.getI());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, this looks nice! What would be the nicest way to manage the different return types?

Comment: Maybe you could define an interface using generics like: `public interface InnerCode<ParameterType,ReturnType> { ReturnType execute(ParameterType parameter); }`

Comment: Remains the problem of different (number and types) ParameterTypes, i tried `private interface InnerCode<ParameterType...,ReturnType>{ReturnType execute(ParameterType... parametertypes);}` but that doesn't work

Comment: this would solve with a [parameterObject](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html), in which you will have a class for that holds all parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer! Isn't there another Method to solve this (Annotation?), because the problem with the above Solution is, that I'm trying to save Lines of Code by adding more of them and complicate the code reading - or would u suggest to leave the boiler plate code? upvote4commitment!

Comment: I would try to check if the [Decorator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) could be applied.